# TeamViewer 8.0.772 crashes on Sony Xperia running ICS 4.0.4

Tags: teamviewer

I am trying to use Teamviewer 8.0.772 to remotely access my computer. However the app is crashing in no time once it is started.

System Info:

- Sony Ericsson xperia Neo V
- ICS 4.0.4

I have re-installed it but nothing works.

Comment: Have you cleared the app data and/or cache?

Answer (score 1):

Please try and clear the app data and cache - this fixed the same issue for me.